# add a item inside a nested schema mongoose with addToSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I know populating schemas is not a new question but I am having a little trouble following the logic on this in regards to multiple schemas. I am working with

```
"mongoose": "^4.8.5",
"express": "^4.15.0",
```

I have a schema with a collection of caffeine drinks.  When a user selects a drink i would like for that drink to be assigned to the user.

** If at any point I am missing something simple in the architecture please let me know.  This project has been my intro to mongodb.

I am reading through populating on the mongoose documentation  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html.

Essentially, if I am to assign the drinks to the list it looks like I want to add them as a reference in an array.  This was my approach with **caffeine_list**

```
const SelectedDrinks = require('./userDrinks');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  caffeine_list: caffeine_list: [ // attempting to reference selected drinks
    { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'SelectedDrinks' 
    }
]
```

})

SelectedDrinks comes from the schema below.  I added a reference to the user as the creator below

```
const User = require('./user');

let userDrinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
      creator : { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User' 
      },
      caffeine: Number,
      mgFloz: Number,
      name: String,
      size: Number,
      updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});
```

This is where I start to get confused. I initially tried populate but could not get it going.  If that was correct please let me know.

In regards to my task of adding a selected drink to the user I used addToSet.  I was hoping that this would give me the drink info. I did my set up like so....

```
const User = require('../../models/user');
const UserDrinks = require('../../models/userDrinks');


router.post('/addDrink', (req, res, next) => {
  let newDrink = new UserDrinks({
      creator: req.body.creator,
      caffeine: req.body.caffeine,
      mgFloz: req.body.mgFloz,
      name: req.body.name,
      size: req.body.size,
      updated_at: req.body.updated_at
  });

newDrink.save( (err) => {
    if(err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        User.findOne({ _id: newDrink.creator},  (err, user) => {
            user.caffeine_list.addToSet(newDrink)
            user.save( function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }else {
                    res.status(201).json(newDrink);
                }
            })
        })
    }

})
```

});

However, after i do a post in postman I check **caffeine_list** and the result is

```
"caffeine_list" : [
    ObjectId("58d82a5ff2f85e3f21822ab5"),
    ObjectId("58d82c15bfdaf03f853f3864")
],
```

Ideally I would like to have an array of objects being passed with the caffeine info like so

```
 "caffeine_list" : [
    {
      "creator": "58d6245cc02b0a0e6db8d257",
      "caffeine": 412,
      "mgFloz": 218.7,
      "name": "1.95 Perfect Drink!",
      "size": 42.93,
      "updated_at": "2017-03-24T18:04:06.357Z"
    }
 ]
```

Comment: The last parts can't be right. Your POST handler only returns the newly-added drink which is an object. Be specific on your question. What you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish exactly what I noted in the caffeine_list array of the userSchema.  I am trying to add drinks to the userSchema inside the post.  I am able to find the userId in mongo and the caffeine_list array.  The problem is I am adding the Object Id.  as opposed to newDrink.

Answer (score 1):

**Change your else part with below code instead of findOne and save use update**

```
      User.update(
    { _id: newDrink.creator},            
    {  $addToSet:{ 
      caffeine_list: newDrink
  }}).exec(function (err, updatedrink){

    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }else {
        res.status(201).json(updatedrink);
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure this is the best approach I did find this to be give me the result that I was desiring.  I had to make two small changes and I was able to get the **caffeine_list** to give me the desired response

I had to access the schema for selected drinks

```
    const SelectedDrinks = require('./userDrinks').schema; //** need schema
```

Afterwards I was able to change

```
caffeine_list: [
   { 
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'UserDrinks' // name of the file
   }
]
```

to

```
caffeine_list: [SelectedDrinks]
```

Now that I have the schema I am able to add the drinks directly into the **caffeine_list** on the UserSchema.